# JS Object property copying: what is happening behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, for-in-loop

Let's say I want to copy two objects the old way:

```
var firstObj = {
  key1: "val1",
  key2: "val2"
}

var secondObj = {
  key1: "val1",
  key2: "val2",
  key3: "val3",
  key4: "val4"
}
```

If I use the solution

```
for(var k in firstObj) secondObj[k]=firstObj[k];
```

Is clear that i'm only referring to that object's properties' contents and not to the property itself. How is the property name also copied?

I'm asking because the "k" refers to "key1,key2,...keyn" while "obj[k]" refers to what the property contains. 
If I'm doing a for loop to list both properties and their contents, I have to refer to both "k" and obj[k] like this:

```
for(var k in secondObj) {
  console.log(k + " : " + secondObj[k]);
  }
```

but when referring to two objects, I don't refer to 'k' anymore

Comment: `secondObj[k]=firstObj[k];` - variable k contains the property name of the first object. With your code you create a new property on the second object with the same name. That's how the property's name also gets copied.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the property name also copied?

With a variable `k` and a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with bracket notation.

> ```
> object.property    // dot notation
> object['property']   // bracket notation
> ```

```
for (var k in firstObj) secondObj[k] = firstObj[k];
//                               ^^^
```

`k` contains a string and not a property and not an object.

Basically it says take property name `k` of the object `secondObj` and assign a value to it.

After the assignment, object `secondObj` has a property with the name of the value of `k`.

Comment: what I don't understand is why do BOTH the "k" the property name as well as the firstObj[k] (referring to the content of that property)  get copied, because inside the loop I'm only referring to the actual "value" of "k". How does the loop know to put the property name - k - inside as well?

Comment: maybe it is  easier to split the assignment into two parts with a temp variable, like `temp = firstObj[k]; secondObj[k] = temp;` the first part does not know from the second part. common is the access via a string as peroperty accessor. once you have a value assigned to a property, the object itself knows which properties it have.

Comment: Ok, so when referring to object properties, the key is always related to the value then? I don't need to specifically refer to it? It may sound stupid but then, if I have 2 objects: `var obj1 = { food: "peter", ingredients: "doherty" } and obj2 = {name: "john", surname: "doe"};` how can I change the property keys from obj2 to obj1 so that I get `obj1 = {name: "peter", surname: "doherty" }`

Comment: yes, the key is the accessor to the value inside of the object.